# Using getRange to return entire column of data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Code is as follows:

```
    function AdjAvail() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var masterSheet =ss.getSheetByName("Master");
var masterAvail = ss.getSheetByName("Unique Territories - Availability");

var apptTerr = masterSheet.getRange(6,2).getValue();
var apptTime = masterSheet.getRange(9,5).getValue();

var lastCol = masterAvail.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = masterAvail.getLastRow();

var lookupTime = masterAvail.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];
var lookupTerr = masterAvail.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues();

var timeIndex = lookupTime.indexOf(apptTime)+4;
// var terrIndex = lookupTerr.indexof(apptTerr)+4;


Logger.log(lookupTerr);
```

Directly below works perfectly and returns an entire row of data:

```
var lookupTime = masterAvail.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];
```

The next line below returns all data I want, but inside closed brackets.

```
var lookupTerr = masterAvail.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues();
```

Or if I adjust to the following, it only returns the top-left cell:

```
var lookupTerr = masterAvail.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues()[0];
```

I need to return the entire array so I can run the function below:

```
var terrIndex = lookupTerr.indexof(apptTerr)+4;
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm lost, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten the 2D-array obtained by .getValues() with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
var lookupTerr = masterAvail.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues().flat();
```

and see if that helps?